# imprimir a menor string lexicograficamente possível que pode ser obtida ao remover no máximo 1 caractere da string

Tags: python-3.x

Irei receber um numero inteiro e uma string`` terei q imprimir a menor string lexicograficamente possível que pode ser obtida ao remover no máximo 1 caractere da string.

Achei uns codigos antigos, só que nehum se aproximou do resultado que eu desejo, por exemplo:

```
y=input()
i=n=l=len(y)
while i:
    if (y[:i]*l)[:l]==y:n=i
        i-=1
        x=y[:n];y=x*2
while i<n:
    x=min(x,y[i:i+n])
    i+=1
print(x)
```

Por exemplo: Recebo o numero 26 e a string: lolthisiscoolfreehackforya, e a resposta seria: llthisiscoolfreehackforya

Comment: Não entendi o motivo de você ter que informar o número (no caso o 26). Pelo que entendi do problema creio que basta você verificar: 1) se o primeiro caractere é lexicograficamente maior que o segundo caractere então remova o primeiro caractere ("baaa" torna-se "aaa"); 2) se o primeiro caractere é menor ou igual ao segundo caractere então procure, a partir do segundo caractere, um caractere que seja lexicograficamente maior que o primeiro e remova tal caractere ("aaba" torna-se "aaa").

Comment: é isso mesmo , mas eu não tenho ideia de como fazer isso em código

Comment: com certeza tem outro jeito de fazer, mas você pode for fazer com dois laço for, percorrendo cada caractere da string e comparando com o próximo, quando a comparação for true você usa um break pra terminar.

Comment: tem ideia de como ficaria esse codigo ?

Answer (score 0):

Acho que é mais ou menos isso que vc procura.

```
>>> a = 'lolthisiscoolfreehackforya'
>>> n = 0
>>> while ord(a[n+1]) < ord(a[n]) and n < len(a) - 1:
...     n += 1
...
>>> a[:n+1] + a[n+2:]
'llthisiscoolfreehackforya'
>>>
```

**NOTA** A linha `a[:n+1] + a[n+2:]` pode dar erro se n for minor 1 ou 2 que o tamanho da string. Tem que fazer um `if`...

Espero ter ajudado